# Servicestack OrmLite deleting many to many

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Let's say I have a `ListingEvent` class and a `UserAccount` class.

A `ListingEvent` can have many `UsersAttending` and a `UserAccount` can attend many `ListingEvents`.

The classes look like:

```
public class UserAccount
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id {
        get ;
        set;
    }

    public string Name {
        get ;
        set;
    }

    public UserAccount()
    {
        ListingEventsAttending = new List<UserAccountListingEvent> ();
    }

    [Reference]
    public List<UserAccountListingEvent> ListingEventsAttending {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class UserAccountListingEvent{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Model.AttendingStatus Status { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(UserAccount))]
    public int UserAccountId {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [References(typeof(ListingEvent))]
    public int ListingEventId {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ListingEvent
{
    public ListingEvent()
    {
        UsersAttending = new List<UserAccountListingEvent>();
    }

    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id {
        get ;
        set;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<UserAccountListingEvent> UsersAttending { get; set; }

    public void RemoveUserAttending(UserAccount user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        UsersAttending.RemoveAll(u => u.UserAccountId == user.Id);
    }
}
```

And I get a ListingEvent that has my UserAccount attending with:

```
var listingEvent = db.LoadSingleById<Model.ListingEvent> (request.Id);
```

And I can see that the user with the correct Id is attending so call `RemoveUserAttending` to remove the user. I can now see the user is not attending so I call:

```
db.Save (listingEvent, references: true);
```

But - now when I go to fetch that ListingEvent again the user is back to attending.

So my question is:

1. should the above work as expected?
2. if not - how should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.Save()` only `INSERT` or `UPDATE` entities i.e. it doesn't `DELETE` them.

To delete, retrieve the entities or entity Ids you want to delete and use OrmLite's `db.Delete*` API's explicitly, e.g. something like:

```
var removeUsersAttendingIds = listingEvent.UsersAttending
    .Where(u => u.UserAccountId == user.Id)
    .Select(u => u.Id);

db.DeleteByIds<UserAccountListingEvent>(removeUsersAttendingIds);
```

Comment: This is a bit of an issue because now I have to take that logic out of my domain which will leave it a bit anaemic - how are people dealing with this? Should I be considering an oRM that does change tracking? :/

Comment: OrmLite's always been a non-surprising ORM that retains a high affinity with SQL, i.e. you would need to take a very similar approach with SQL or any Micro ORM. If you blobbed it instead (i.e. not making it a [Reference] type) than your approach will work. Otherwise sure you can use a heavier ORM with change tracking if you prefer.

Comment: Cheers - gonna spike some code - not used NHibernate for a v long time :p